# Lectrosonics LMa's vs Sennheiser EW100's

Tags: radiomics, lectrosonics

I have two Sennheiser EW100 (G1's I think) radio mic kits, but they only put out 10mW and I often have issues with dropouts.
Now I am looking at purchasing the Lectrosonics LMa series of transmitters and the UCR100 receivers, together with the MP152 lapel mics.
Does anyone have experience with the LMa and UCR100 setup and the MP152 microphones?  I'd love to hear your views and comments!

Answer (score 2):

We finally replaced the last of our Sennheiser's with SMQV's paired with the SRa's. We have also been using the LMa's with the UCR411a's. They are used in a run and gun style all day event.

We don't have the same setup as you but I have to say Lectrosonics are magical.

Comment: +1. I also use LMa's, 401's, and 411's. All stellar, bombproof, and never an issue when used properly.